# Intellij doesn't highlight incompatible pattern type of case class that has many parameters more than 22

Tags: scala, intellij-idea

When the number of parameters of case class is more than 22, Intellij doesn't highlight imcompatible pattern type.

For example, below code makes error.

```scala
val data = Some(Data())
data match {
  case Some(Data("")) => println(1)
  case _ => println(2)
}

...

case class Data(a: String = "", b: String = "")
```

However, below code doesn't make error.

```scala
val data = Some(Data())
data match {
  case Some(Data("")) => println(1)
  case _ => println(2)
}

...

case class Data(a: String = "", b: String = "", ..., z: String = "")
```

This only happens if the number of parameters of class `Data` is more than 22.

In compile time, both of the above codes make same error like "Pattern type is incompatible with expected type, found: None.type, required: (String, ... String)".

And I can't refactor for that class to have smaller parameters because it is just the implementation of a JSON communication protocol like OpenRTB.

How can I fix it?

Comment: You can create a bug report at JetBrains bug tracker (project Scala) https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/projects/07182d7c-03b1-4cbd-a23e-edc8628b426d